# MessageDriven app doesnot start due to JMS resources on IBM WAS

Tags: jms, websphere, ibm-mq, message-driven-bean

I built a simple MDB application which listens a jms.Queue, had deployed it on IBM WAS 8.5.5 (with IBM MQ as a JMS broker) and when trying to start it I received the following error (sorry for cyrillic symbols, tried to translate closely):

```
    [11.10.16 16:01:43:207 MSK] 00000068 AdminHelper   A   ADMN1009I: /**An attempt to start application earMdb*/Предпринята попытка запустить приложение earMdb. 
[11.10.16 16:01:43:228 MSK] 00000068 CompositionUn A   WSVR0190I:/**Module started*/Запуск составного модуля WebSphere:cuname=earMdb в BLA WebSphere:blaname=earMdb. 
[11.10.16 16:01:43:263 MSK] 00000068 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0200I: /**Application is starting*/Запуск приложения: earMdb 
[11.10.16 16:01:43:263 MSK] 00000068 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0204I: Приложение: earMdb  Уровень компоновки: Неизвестен
[11.10.16 16:01:43:302 MSK] 00000068 SharedEJBRunt I   WSVR0037I: Запуск файла JAR EJB: ejb-mdb.jar
[11.10.16 16:01:43:327 MSK] 00000068 AbstractEJBRu I   CNTR0180I: /**Message driven object EJB MdbListener in ejb-mdb.jar module associated with activation specification jms/mdbtest/queue/activespec*/Управляемый сообщениями объект EJB MdbListener в модуле ejb-mdb.jar приложения earMdb связан с спецификацией активации jms/mdbtest/queue/activespec. 
[11.10.16 16:01:43:338 MSK] 00000068 RAWrapperImpl E   J2CA0089E: /**method activateEndpoint in JavaBean ResourceAdapter cells/AParfenovNode02Cell/nodes/AParfenovNode02/resources.xml#J2CResourceAdapter_1476114690841 was not executed; exception is javax.resource.ResourceException: endpointActivation failed*/Метод activateEndpoint в JavaBean ResourceAdapter cells/AParfenovNode02Cell/nodes/AParfenovNode02/resources.xml#J2CResourceAdapter_1476114690841 не выполнен; получена исключительная ситуация javax.resource.ResourceException: endpointActivation failed 
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.activateEndpoint(ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.java:372)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RAWrapperImpl.activateEndpoint(RAWrapperImpl.java:1105)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RALifeCycleManagerImpl.activateEndpoint(RALifeCycleManagerImpl.java:1754)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.MessageEndpointFactoryImpl.activateEndpoint(MessageEndpointFactoryImpl.java:168)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.startMDBs(EJBContainerImpl.java:4714)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.WASEJBRuntimeImpl.startMDBs(WASEJBRuntimeImpl.java:683)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime.startModule(AbstractEJBRuntime.java:716)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.startModule(SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.java:336)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.start(EJBContainerImpl.java:3576)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1175)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:774)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1374)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2179)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:663)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5384)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5600)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:677)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:621)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1266)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1148)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:252)
    at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
    at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1142)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:995)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:774)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.AdminServiceCommands$InvokeCmd.execute(AdminServiceCommands.java:251)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper.invoke(MBeanHelper.java:241)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.appdeployment.ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.execute(ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.java:578)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:955)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:325)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl incompatible with javax.jms.Destination
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.DestinationBuilder.createDestination(DestinationBuilder.java:152)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointDeployment.startDelivery(MessageEndpointDeployment.java:317)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointDeployment.<init>(MessageEndpointDeployment.java:224)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.ResourceAdapterImpl.endpointActivation(ResourceAdapterImpl.java:397)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.activateUnderRAClassLoaderContext(ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.java:646)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.activateEndpoint(ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.java:362)
    ... 105 more

[11.10.16 16:01:43:349 MSK] 00000068 SharedEJBRunt E   WSVR0040E: Метод addEjbModule не выполнен для ejb-mdb.jar
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: javax.resource.ResourceException: endpointActivation failed /**Method addEjbModule for ejb-mdb.jar was not executed com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: javax.resource.ResourceException: endpointActivation failed*/
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.startMDBs(EJBContainerImpl.java:4718)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.WASEJBRuntimeImpl.startMDBs(WASEJBRuntimeImpl.java:683)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime.startModule(AbstractEJBRuntime.java:716)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.startModule(SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.java:336)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.start(EJBContainerImpl.java:3576)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1175)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:774)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1374)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2179)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:663)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5384)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5600)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:677)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:621)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1266)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1148)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:252)
    at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
    at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1142)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:995)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:774)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.AdminServiceCommands$InvokeCmd.execute(AdminServiceCommands.java:251)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper.invoke(MBeanHelper.java:241)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.appdeployment.ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.execute(ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.java:578)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:955)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:325)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: endpointActivation failed
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.activateEndpoint(ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.java:372)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RAWrapperImpl.activateEndpoint(RAWrapperImpl.java:1105)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RALifeCycleManagerImpl.activateEndpoint(RALifeCycleManagerImpl.java:1754)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.MessageEndpointFactoryImpl.activateEndpoint(MessageEndpointFactoryImpl.java:168)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.startMDBs(EJBContainerImpl.java:4714)
    ... 101 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl incompatible with javax.jms.Destination
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.DestinationBuilder.createDestination(DestinationBuilder.java:152)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointDeployment.startDelivery(MessageEndpointDeployment.java:317)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointDeployment.<init>(MessageEndpointDeployment.java:224)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.ResourceAdapterImpl.endpointActivation(ResourceAdapterImpl.java:397)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.activateUnderRAClassLoaderContext(ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.java:646)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.activateEndpoint(ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.java:362)
    ... 105 more
```

My message driven
ejb-mdb module **MdbListener.java**:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", 
    propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")},
    name = "MdbListener")
public class MdbListener implements MessageListener {
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        System.out.println("MdbListener called...");
    }
}
```

ejb-mdb module **ejb-jar.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns="http:/java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd" version="3.0" metadata-complete="false">
    <display-name>My MDB</display-name>
    <enterprise-beans>
        <message-driven>
            <display-name>MdbListener</display-name>
            <ejb-name>MdbListener</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>ru.aparfenov.mdb.MdbListener</ejb-class>
            <message-destination-ref>
                <message-destination-ref-name>jms/mdbtest/queue</message-destination-ref-name>
                <message-destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</message-destination-type>
                <message-destination-usage>Consumes</message-destination-usage>
                <message-destination-link>jms/mdbtest/queue</message-destination-link>
            </message-destination-ref>
        </message-driven>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

ejb-mdb module **ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar-bnd xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
    <message-driven name="MdbListener">
        <message-destination-ref name="jms/mdbtest/queue" binding-name="jms/mdbtest/queue" />
    </message-driven>
</ejb-jar-bnd>
```

When deploing my ear I was always asked to point out the JNDI name for target resource.
[image: IBM WAS deploy master clause]
All my JMS resources: queue connection factory, queue, activation specification and WebSphere MQ messaging provider are all in the same **Cell=AParfenovNode02Cell** scope. And resource adapter sees my active spec in J2C activation specifications with corresponding scope.
My messaging provider native library path is set to **C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib64**.
Also I have a web application which successfully uses the same JMS resources and writes messages into **jms/mdbtest/queue**.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to use this for your JNDI locations:

```
jms/mdbtest/queue            # Queue        
jms/mdbtest/queue/activespec #ActivationSpec
```

but **jms/mdbtest/queue** is a Context since it has children.

Instead try something like:

```
jms/mdbtest/queue/queue
jms/mdbtest/queue/activespec
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the realy non-obvious mistake which I would never might suggest. Now it works precisely - I changed my queue JNDI name to jms/mdbtest/localqueue and updated the corresponding references in activespec.